# Template function that can compare different data types c++

Tags: c++, templates

I need to write a template function that can compare integers, chars and strings, but there is a condition: strings must be compared by their lenghts.

I have some code:

```
template<typename data>
bool compare(data left, data right)
{
    if (typeid(left) == typeid(string))
    {
        return strlen((char*)left) > strlen((char*)right) ? true : false;
    }
    return left > right ? true : false;
}
```

When I compare two strings, there is an error in line 6: `C2440 'type cast': cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'char*'`

I tried another way, I replaced line 6 with `return left.length() > right.lenght() ? true : false;`, but if I compare non-string data, I have an error: `C2228 left of '.length' must have class/struct/union`

So, how can I implement this function correctly ?

Comment: You could specialize the template for string.

Comment: You need `if constexpr` for that or use tag-dispatch. If you don't want to deal with template stuff just write a function that is overloaded on `char`, `int` and `string` that always returns a number that you use for comparison.

Comment: Write a specialization for `std::string`: `template <> bool compare(const std::string& left, const std::string& right) { ... }`.

Comment: simple solution : overload the function for string. [You should avoid function template specialisation](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specialize the template for string:

```
template<typename data>
bool compare(data left, data right)
{
    return left > right;
}

template<>
bool compare(std::string left, std::string right)
{
    return left.length() > right.length();
}
```

Also the ternary operator is not required. Rather than `return left > right ? true : false;` you could just `return left > right;`

Also, watch out for character literals decaying into pointers:
`compare("Hi", "There");` would compare the pointer addresses. So the following is probably also required:

```
template<>
bool compare(const char* left, const char* right)
{
    return std::strlen(left) > std::strlen(right);
}
```

Comment: "Could" should be "should". <g>

Comment: Is this specialization or overload?

Comment: @Zereges it's specialisation, no templates are involved in overload.